# Scattering projectile particle with defined momentum

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, scattering

When studying collisions in quantum mechanics you are interested in finding trough the cross section's data the expression of the probability current density $j$ which is strictly connected to your system's wave function $\psi (x,t)$ that you want to determine. Now in the treatment of the problem (in the lecture notes I'm reading, and also in standard books) I often deal with projectile particles with defined momentum $p_k=\hbar k$ prepared (I quote) "at spacial infinity in the remote past". How can I deal with particles with defined momentum, and therefore a sort of real physical system described by monochromatic plane waves? I have made some guesses:

- the fact that the particles are prepared at spacial infinity and in the remote past suggests me that I can contruct a wave packet arbitrarily peaked around a value $k$ at its origin (thus at $-\infty$). But due to time evolution when my projectile reaches the scattering center it will be no more peaked around a single value, so what is the point? I know that, for a packet like a Gaussian one, the time evolution leaves the mean value $<p>_t=p_0$, with $p_0$ initial value of $p$ associated with my initial condition $\psi_0$; is thus the $p_k$ of my question the mean value of my packet?
- In physical situations (I had this hint from my lecture notes) I have a beam of nearly identical particles generated in the laboratory, and thus I have a discrete set of eigenvalues of my energy $w_k$ and the corresponding eigenfunctions are thus normalizable and non degenerate because of the boundary condition of having my particles confined in the laboratory. But the linear dimensions of my room let me approximate the values of my energy with a rather continuous spectrum and thus approximate my normalizable eigenfunctions $\phi_k$ with non normalizable plane waves. At this point what is the formal procedure I make to treat something normalizable as it's not?

N.B. I cannot provide you a link of my lecture notes since it is protected material of my university so you must have credentials to access to it, sorry!

Comment: "it will be no more peaked around a single value, so what is the point?" The point is that the scattering process is described by a dynamics that is linear on the total Hilbert space. Since wave packets are linear superpositions of plane waves, knowing how plane waves behave, in principle allows you to figure out how any wave packet behaves. "what is the formal procedure I make to treat something normalizable as it's not?" Periodic boundary conditions. Or Dirac delta functions if you prefer to extend the lab to the entire space.

Comment: @udrv Basically, you are saying that i deal with a single plane wave with defined momentum, even if it is an idealization, because i can build every type of real situation since i can represent any wave function as superposition of plane waves, am I right? For what concerns the periodic boundary conditions, can you go further or give me any reference where i can look about it please? Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Correct about the plane wave idealization. For an idea about periodic b.c.,   check for instance Sec.5.9(pg.54) of http://wcchew.ece.illinois.edu/chew/course/QMALL20121005.pdf. But any number of QM intro texts will have something on it. Found a nice example of its use in a simple scattering problem in Sec.6.2(pg.89) of https://www.physics.harvard.edu/uploads/files/thesesPDF/lupusax.pdf.

Comment: @udrv thank you very much, you made it quite clear and the links were useful.